# ValueError: Must pass 2-d input when trying to return statsmodels MNLogit confidence intervals

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

The following code should run a MNLogit model and return the confidence intervals. It successfully returns the summary and you can see the confidence intervals there, but when trying to return the confidence intervals via conf_int(), I get a ValueError: Must pass 2-d input.

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

tmp = pd.read_csv('http://surveyanalysis.org/images/8/82/TrickedLogitMaxDiffExample.csv')
model = sm.MNLogit.from_formula('Choice ~ 1+B+C+D+E+F', tmp, missing='drop')
res = model.fit(method='ncg')
print(res.summary())
res.conf_int()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-255-a332500964e4> in <module>()
      6 res = model.fit(method='ncg')
      7 print(res.summary())
----> 8 res.conf_int()

~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/base/wrapper.py in wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
     93             obj = data.wrap_output(func(results, *args, **kwargs), how[0], how[1:])
     94         elif how:
---> 95             obj = data.wrap_output(func(results, *args, **kwargs), how)
     96         return obj
     97 

~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/base/data.py in wrap_output(self, obj, how, names)
    405     def wrap_output(self, obj, how='columns', names=None):
    406         if how == 'columns':
--> 407             return self.attach_columns(obj)
    408         elif how == 'rows':
    409             return self.attach_rows(obj)

~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/base/data.py in attach_columns(self, result)
    522             return Series(result, index=self.param_names)
    523         else:  # for e.g., confidence intervals
--> 524             return DataFrame(result, index=self.param_names)
    525 
    526     def attach_columns_eq(self, result):

~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    304             else:
    305                 mgr = self._init_ndarray(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype,
--> 306                                          copy=copy)
    307         elif isinstance(data, (list, types.GeneratorType)):
    308             if isinstance(data, types.GeneratorType):

~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _init_ndarray(self, values, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    461         # by definition an array here
    462         # the dtypes will be coerced to a single dtype
--> 463         values = _prep_ndarray(values, copy=copy)
    464 
    465         if dtype is not None:

~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _prep_ndarray(values, copy)
   5686     return arrays, arr_columns
   5687 
-> 5688 
   5689 def _list_to_arrays(data, columns, coerce_float=False, dtype=None):
   5690     if len(data) > 0 and isinstance(data[0], tuple):

ValueError: Must pass 2-d input
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include the full traceback of your error.

Comment: I think it's a bug... I noticed that if I run the model using the normal (non-formula) syntax, it works correctly, but with the formula syntax it doesn't.

Comment: Can you show your `tmp` variable? Does it have the columns specified in the formula?

Comment: Just run `import pandas as pd
tmp = pd.read_csv('http://surveyanalysis.org/images/8/82/TrickedLogitMaxDiffExample.csv')
tmp.head()`

Comment: @BirdLaw - I have tried the non-formula syntax and it is still broken - has anyone found an answer on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug for which a fix has been made that will be out in milestone 0.10 aparently: https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/3651#issuecomment-300511723

There is, however, a work around. You can get an array version of the confidence intervals from the results object:

`res = model.fit(method='ncg')
res._results.conf_int()`

This is not entirely brilliant as you can't see which CI belongs to what. However, if you compare it to the res.summary() report you can see the CIs are in the same order, which helps.

Thanks to josef-pkt for this: https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/3883